# How do you get the current seed of Random in C#?

Tags: c#, random

In my game I'm going to use random values to pick the reward the player gets from a chest. The problem is that you can quick save and quick load and that means they can keep reloading to re-randomize until they get what they want. Is there some way that I could get the current seed value of my `Random` object and possibly return to that same point when they load so that they couldn't abuse the randomization?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure on **getting** the seed, but you could save the value you give to the `Random` object. Remember, there are two constructors. The second is `Random(Int32)`, so if you set the seed yourself (an easy enough value is [Environment.TickCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount)), you could store that value somewhere before you pass it to the constructor. If you haven't read it yet, check out the MSDN documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.

Comment: I have it save the seed like that now and it's working great, thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend to think about what you've achieved - basically user now guaranteed to have next random event tied to this Random object to have particular outcome depending solely on initial configuration. May be OK for your game.

Comment: Note that if you are using the random object for anything else too, you may not be guaranteed to get the same reward each time. For example, if there are two different game objects with random event triggers that use the same random number generator, you could save, trigger one then the other, reload and trigger again in a different order to get different results. If the objects are both chests, and they each have the same reward set to choose from, then you will still get the same rewards, just swapped, but if object type or reward sets differ you will not get the consistency you are seeking.

Comment: This method requires creating a new Random object every time you wish to generate a random number. -1

Comment: @Jim You care to elaborate on the down-vote? I don't mind down-votes, but I don't get where you're going. The OP only asked how to retain the seed value; what he does afterwards is up to him and his implementation.

Comment: SLaks' answer is correct. Your answer is helpful, but does not scale well since it requires object creation each time the seed is "retrieved". I probably wouldn't have down-voted it if it wasn't marked as correct.

Comment: If you look at the [source code of Random](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,bb77e610694e64ca) you'll find the following: `public Random() : this(Environment.TickCount) { }` So all you have to do is get `Environment.TickCount` store it in a class field and feed it to the constructor. **There you go, you have the seed saved. :)**

Comment: Note that `System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond` only goes from `0` to `1000` which isn't great. Better use `Environemt.TickCount` (as @Shakaron pointed out) (rolls every ± 50 days and has a 15ms accurary)

Answer (score 20):

This is not possible.

Instead, you can serialize the `Random` instance using binary serialization.
`Random` is `[Serializable]`, and the seed and internal state will persist.

Note, however, that saving the random seed allows your players to predict the future, which is very useful if you allow saving in battle.

Also note that users can still save, open the chest, load, perform an action that generates a random number, then get a different item from the chest.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I was thinking about that as well that they could still go and use up that number on another chest and then come back. What I mostly wanted to avoid was constant reloading 50+ times to try and get a rare item for example so if that doesn't bother me too much if they use that random elsewhere.

Comment: You could generate the contents of all chests (and similar items) up-front, when loading the level. Create a new random instance just for level loading and ensure that chests are initialized in some well-defined order. After loading throw the instance away, but remember the initial seed for the savegame.

Comment: That's another option that I might just do Gnafoo that way it's all generated with the map data and then there would be nothing to worry about.

Comment: +1. You may also consider using multiple Random objects for different types of "random" events. I.e. eye candy stuff to be on one Random object, while battle outcome on another and loot on yet another object.

Comment: `This is not possible.` this is exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, the `Seed` [isn't stored](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,92e3cf6e56571d5a,references) as it is not relevant for the algorithm after initialization. One of its derivatives, `mj`, is stored in the `SeedArray` though, you can check that using Reflection to compare both `Random` instances:

```
int subtraction = (Seed == Int32.MinValue) ? Int32.MaxValue : Math.Abs(Seed);
mj = MSEED - subtraction;
SeedArray[55]=mj;
```

So all you have to do is to check the last element (index 55) in the `SeedArray`. This is the only place `Seed` is used.

[Moved answer from deleted question [How to determine if two Random instances have the same seed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47750844/993547)]

Comment: I'm not sure it's reliable way. It's seems better to compare whole `SeedArray` of two Random instances to determine that they will produce the same sequence, not just last item. Because this array is modified during `Next` calls (including last element) and so it might happen that last elements are the same, but the rest are not.

Comment: That is a good point. I didn't go through the entire algorithm to check that, but it seems you are right @Evk

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my (deleted because duplicate) question here :-)

Comment: I guess it was better to put it here :) @TimSchmelter

Comment: And I think you need to take `inext` into account too. SeedArray + inext seems to completely determine the output, so they being equal in two Random instances should prove they will produce identical output.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the random reward as a hash function of:

1. some seed that is assigned when you begin a *new* game, and is persisted in *saved* games; and
2. some constant property of a chest that is invariant across all games (e.g. a fixed ID, or its position if it never moves).

This method has the advantage that a given chest will always yield the same reward in a given game, no matter how many times you save and replay, even if chests are opened in different orders, or other 'random' events are triggered in different orders. Also each chest's reward is independent of other chests' rewards, so long as the chest's property used in the hash is independent.

In the following example `GetRewardId` generates a reward ID as a hash of the game seed XORed with the x coordinate of a chest. It uses `Random` to perform the hash, by using the hash input as the `Random` object's seed, and taking the first randomly generated number as the output.

```
private static int GetRewardId(int seed, float coord, int numRewards)
{
    int tempSeed = BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(coord), 0) ^ seed;
    return new Random(tempSeed).Next(numRewards);
}

int seed  = new Random().Next();
int numDifferentRewards = 5;
float xCoordinate = chest.Position.X;
int rewardId = GetRewardId(seed, xCoordinate, numDifferentRewards);
```

If many of your chests are likely to be aligned in sace, you may want to choose a different property, or use additional dimensions, by XORing with the y and/or z coordinates too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just use this as per MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx

```
Random(seed)
```

where seed is some value I've loaded from storage.

Comment: -1 - the question is exactly opposite - how to get current seed, so it can later be used for Random(seed) call after reload.

Comment: @Alexei: If you've saved the seed somewhere then you can get the seed at a later point in time. It doesn't have to come from the Random object and it can't as far as I know.

Comment: The problem is if you seeded the Random with say 5, and called Next several times (i.e. got 3,7,6,1) and expect next value to be 13, but instead reseeding with original value 5 due to load next Random will be 3 instead of 13. You need current seed value (internal data of Random object), not the original one that you can easily remember.

Comment: Looking at accepted answer it is exactly what OP wanted... Edit your answer so I can give you your 1 back for having awesome psychic powers :)

Answer (score 1):

This is only related on a tangent, but in case anyone is wondering why `Random` doesn't have a property called `Seed` or a method called `GetSeed()`, I'm willing to wager that it's likely due to security concerns: Would you want to expose the inner workings of your "random" number generator to the outside world? Absolutely not! Otherwise, some client code could poke around until it got the values you were using and then do nasty and unintended things with them.

Comment: Security is not the reason for not adding that property: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,dec894a7e816e665,references You are confusing a random generator with what you find in [the `System.Security.Cryptography`-namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in the reference implementation from Microsoft, the no arg ctor's seed value is not even saved, let alone exposed for access:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,bb77e610694e64ca

However, as you can also see in the reference implementation, the value you can pass in (probably should -- I know I do), just like they do, is: `Environment.TickCount`

So save that to a variable, then pass that variable in to the ctor that takes an arg and you now know the seed.  Not after the fact, but this should be sufficient for whatever your intent is.

Answer (score -3):

I recommend you to generate a random number and use it as a seed number to your real random number generator. By this method you have a seed number that is actually a random number and you can save your seed number for further using.

Comment: Seeding a pseudo-random number generator with a pseudo-random number still gives you a pseudo-random number. This also doesn't really answer the question.