# Get seed of Random object without passing in the seed?

Tags: java, c#, random

Does the random object always contains a seed, even when not given one? And if so is it possible to `get` this seed?

Motivation:
I want my program to be random but i want to be able to reproduce it whenever i want. What i currently do is generate a random number, store it and put it as seed into another Random object that i use for the actual program. This way i can look up the generated seed if i want to reproduce anything.

I would like to know this for `Java` and `C#` since these are my main languages and this question struck me a couple times working in both languages.

Comment: Your current approach is a good one. The seed is used to generate a larger set of state within the RNG - and that state is generally *not* visible.

Comment: For `.NET`, the online source (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs#bb77e610694e64ca) shows it uses `Environment.TickCount` to initialize the random object, however, there's no way to get the value back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seed will be generated for you implicitly if you don't provide the random constructor with one. To set a seed and use it again at some other point in code or reproduce anything, try this:

```
long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
Random rand = new Random(seed);
System.out.println(seed);
```

Comment: This actually is interesting, simple, effective and efficient.

Comment: This is how you can do in Java. Not sure about C# as I m a Java Developer. Hope it will help you

Comment: Hard to pick the winning answer, i guess you can use the rep more then @Douglas :). The answer is pretty much the same.

Comment: Yes, the algorithm used is pretty much the same. The only difference is the language used to achieve the results. Just checked his answer now :) Thankyou

Comment: @JeeshuMittal: This answer was posted before mine, and given that both met your requirements equally, then I agree with picking this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question from a C# perspective just take a look at the documentation - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx). For the `Random` classes parameterless constructor it says:

> Initializes a new instance of the Random class, using a time-dependent default seed value

So yes, if you don't supply a seed the runtime will use a default one.

Again, looking at the documentation you can see you can't find the seed used if you don't supply it.

As for wanting to be able to consistently produce random numbers, you could create an `IRandomNumberGenerator` interface and create 2 implementations. One would make calls to the `Random` class, the other could be used for testing purposes and would simply return whatever you wish. Then you could use dependency injection to control which implementation is used.

Comment: Thank you, however i'm not looking for a a double implementation. I just do not want any users to put there own seeds but if i for whatever reason need or want to reproduce i want to be able to. So in all cases i need to be able to know the seed. Seeing the other comments and answers it looks like i'm already doing it the correct way.

Comment: While it's true that you can use `Environment.TickCount` as the default seed, it isn't documented and means you are relying on an implementation detail. You may be 99.9999% certain that this detail will never change, but there is no guarantee it won't.

Answer (score 1):

As for `C#` there's no simple way to get the seed from an already initialized object. The best way to do what you want to do is to do it the way you're already doing it (generating the seed, saving it, and then using it in a new Random object).

Other possibility is to save a binary serialized version of the Random object just after its (implicit) initialization. That way though you wouldn't have the seed you could still regenerate the same sequence of 'random' numbers.

Source: [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx), [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986050/how-do-you-get-the-current-seed-of-random-in-c).

And honestly, I highly doubt Java has a way to do it because it would be (at least in my humble opinion) kind of a security hole.

Answer (score 1):

In the .NET Framework, calling the `Random()` constructor is equivalent to calling `Randoom(Environment.TickCount)`. Thus, you could meet your requirement by reading (and storing) `Environment.TickCount` yourself, then initializing your `Random(int)` based on that value.

Thus, instead of calling:

```
Random myRandom = new Random();
```

You could use:

```
int seed = Environment.TickCount;
// optionally store seed for later reuse
Random myRandom = new Random(seed);
```

Comment: So int seed = Environment.TickCount; Random(seed) is basically what i am asking for? there might be a ms or two difference but i'm okay with that.

Comment: @MennoGouw: Yes. There won't be any performance difference (at least, definitely not in the order of milliseconds), except for storing your seed externally (e.g. writing it to disk) – the JIT compiler would likely produce the same code for both initializations.